# Live video stream encoded by libav stops on switch cameras

Tags: java, video-streaming, libav

There are two cameras having switch in between them. Live stream is being encoded by **Libav** . When i change view i.e switch from *Camera1 to Camera2* ,the stream remains same but *Camera1* is detached while *Camera2* is attached  due to which little break in stream makes **avconv** tool to stop encoding .My run time command for encoding is -

```
`avconv -async 15 -re -i rtmp://IP/live/instream -shortest   -s 176*144   -r 10   -b:v 56k   -ab 12k  -ac 1 -ar 22050  -err_detect explode -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://IP/live/instream`.
```

The above command unable to encode live stream continuously broadcast by Flash Media Server and stops encoding.

Comment: any updates on this ? I am using ffmpeg to transcode stream and FFMpeg is also stops due to little break.